# select2, remove option changes data, but not value

Tags: javascript, select, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 for my tagging application. However, I'm having trouble deleting existing tags on items. It's inconsistent, but seems to depend on the item; I can always delete the tag "Bugs" in the following example, but the others can't be removed, regardless of the order in which I try to do so.

The console log shows that the deleted item is removed from data, as it should be, and the removed event identifies the correct item as removed, but no change is seen in the 'val', and thus no change sent to the server.

Code:

```
<input id="id_tags" name="tags" type="text" value="Bugs, Existentialism, Kafkaesque" />    
$("#id_tags").select2({
        tokenSeparators:[","],
        placeholder: "Start typing your tags",
        createSearchChoice: function(term, data){
            if ($(data).filter(function(){
                return this.fields.name.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
                return {
                    id: term,
                    fields: {"name": term}
                };
            }
        },
        multiple:true,
        ajax: {
            url: window.location.origin+'/tagsearch/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function( term, page ) {
                return {tag: term};
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {results: data};
            }
        },
        formatResult: tagformat,
        formatSelection: tagformat,
        maximumSelectionSize: 20,
        formatSelectionTooBig: function(limit) {
            return "Stories are limited to " + limit + " tags.";
        },
        initSelection : function(element, callback){
            var data = [];
            $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
                data.push({id:this, fields:{name:this}});
            });
            callback(data);
        }
    });

$('#id_tags').on("select2-removed", function(e){
        var data = $("#id_tags").select2("data");
        console.log($('#id_tags').select2('val'));
        console.log("removed "+ e.choice.fields.name);
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: put together a jsfiddle of this? are you using ajax to add remove tags to a database table?

Comment: Ajax is only used to pull existing tags for users searching. Adding and removing tags is done on the server post-form submission (no ajax), and works fine (without select2). Console log on the remove function seems to point to a JS problem.

Comment: Not sure how I can run a JS fiddle since the ajax-loaded data is on my localserver. JSON returned from ajax is all in the form of {"id": xxx, "fields": {"name": tag_name}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the spaces from the "value" attribute of the input element.

Change:

```
value="Bugs, Existentialism, Kafkaesque"
```

To:

```
value="Bugs,Existentialism,Kafkaesque"
```

Alternatively, you could trim the space off in your `initSelection` method.

I understand that the spaces should not be there -- otherwise they would be part of the id values -- but I'm not sure why they cause the value to get so messed up.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3o8acnjx/2/) showing the issue, and a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3o8acnjx/3/) with the spaces removed.

Comment: This solved it. I split on ", " instead of "," in `initSelection` and it was solved. Better to solve there since the server default value includes spaces (Django). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, guys! I posted the solution suggested by @sybaritic below.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.split(",")` to `.split(", ")` inside the `initSelection`:

```js
initSelection : function(element, callback){
  var data = [];
  $(element.val().split(", ")).each(function () {
      data.push({id:this, fields:{name:this}});
  });
  callback(data);
}
```